# Integer field changed but still prefix zero not displaying

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I'm using an existing Django project and I have a problem with displaying prefix zero of some numbers

the old models were

```
id_number = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(9999)])
```

I have changed it to

```
id_number = models.CharField(max_length=5, default=""
```

than migrate it

```
python3 manage.py makemigrations
```

then

```
python3 manage.py migrate
```

but it still removing any prefix zero how can I fix that. I'm using PostgreSQL DB?

Comment: A `CharField` should be ok to keep the leading zero. Can you check the type of the column in your database ?
And why exactly do you need prefix zero ?

Comment: How exactly do you set your prefixed integer to that field,  it will not automatically be set to have leading zero

Comment: I don't wat it to automatically setting I need to inter some numbers have leading zero in that model ,

Comment: how I will check the type of the column in my database ? sorry I'm new